# Session login (back arrow of chrome)

Tags: javascript, php, session, session-variables

I have  basic login code system that every values of the textboxes(user inputs) will store in a SESSIONS. After the user's login, my **HOME.php** showed. And in a **HOME.php**, The user clicked the back arrow of google chrome, and it seemed the page is going back to the **INDEX.php** where user logged-in.  I was trying if the sessions in index.php are exist. if not go back to home.php?

How could I prevent if the user try to click the back arrow of chrome and still remain in **home.php**?,

[image]

Comment: This is how it works on almost all sites, are you sure you should be trying to fix it at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check whether the session has set in the `index.php` and if it was set then you should redirect the user to `home.php` else to remain same in the `index.php`

So, In your `index.php` you should have this code

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("Location: home.php");
}
else
{
#Ask for credentials using your form 
}
```

Note : I am using `$_SESSION['user']` you should the name that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what the problem is, but I think you want to check if the user session exists in your `index.php` page. If it does, redirect automatically to `home.php` and if it does not, show the page contents / login form.

Comment: @Sume-mase Exactly the same way you check for a logged-in user in `home.php` except that you redirect instead of show the contents.